# How to programmatically identify landmarks (cemeteries) in Google Maps satellite data?

Tags: google-maps, google-earth, image-classification, machine-learning

I'm searching Google Maps satellite view for cemeteries that are not listed in common repositories of cemeteries.  I've spent a lot of time cruising around satellite mode searching for small cemeteries within a county.  I'd like to figure out a way to programmatically identify cemeteries within a given boundary.  I'm not sure if there's a way to provide a set of training images & then have a program 'crawl' a defined area to identify areas that are likely cemeteries.  For example, the following link shows an example of what the program would identify:

[https://www.google.com/maps/place/35%C2%B036'29.7%22N+76%C2%B052'35.0%22W/@35.60825,-76.8785687](https://www.google.com/maps/place/35%C2%B036%2729.7%22N+76%C2%B052%2735.0%22W/@35.60825,-76.8785687)

Does something like this already exist?

Comment: Please do not advertise within your questions.

Comment: @PolyGeo - I've updated the post to remove references to websites that are known to list cemetery details. The intention wasn't to advertise but to anticipate suggestions from commenters.

Comment: I had already removed what I perceived to be the advertising in my edit.

Comment: I'm not a remote sensing specialist, but to me a cemetery is a "land use", composed of features such as graves, tomb stones, roads, tracks, walls/fence and possibly buildings and may be different configurations based upon religion? So has to be one hell of a machine learning algorithm to work all that out! An alternative source may be open streetmap where humans have already mapped the boundary, given it names and other attributes? Or your websites that you referred to?

Comment: Possibly could try to detect disturbed ground